# HTML button to execute a php script that exe shell script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

this is my first time asking question here so please be kind with me...

I have tried and researched many solutions but not work correctly. I am fairly inexperience with javascript, ajax or php so the way I'm approaching this might not be ideal. I need an html button that upon clicking, will call a script.php that have a exec command. What I have so far is after clicking, the webpage go to and display /script.php but doesn't seem to actually run the exec() block.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="script.php">
    <button name="button">Update Inventory</button>
</form>
```

**script.php:**

```
<?php
exec("cd /home/jenkins/Desktop/automationutils/Python/Inventory/ && ./init.py");
?>
```

I can run php script.php and it works on the cmd. So I don't think the script is wrong... it's just my button is having a problem. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you need to check if exec enabled in php.ini and if your webserver has permissions to run your script.

Comment: Sorry for maybe a dumb questions, but how can I check either of those? For permission, for now i'm setting 777 for all the related files for testing

Comment: However, when I ran "php script.php", exec seems to work though?...

Answer (score 0):

You can include the script to the file that will exec it and put the call in a function and add a listener to run it. 
[Here is an example to get you started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340531/adding-play-pause-to-webgl-in-php-js-only)